cannot pip install sdist from test.pypi.org after following tutorial at https://packaging.python.org/
I am following the tutorial here: https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/tutorials/packaging-projects/
I have tried the tutorial with both the hatchling and setuptools backend examples.
I am only trying to build an sdist, and not building a wheel right now.
In both cases, I'm able to upload build the sdist as a .tar.gz and upload it to pypi.
When trying to pull the package down and install it in a local environment using pip, I am getting the following errors:

Does anyone know what this error means?
Attached below is my pyproject.toml and a screenshot of my project layout:

[build-system]
requires = ["setuptools>=61.0"]
build-backend = "setuptools.build_meta"

[project]
name = "example_package_brickman"
version = "0.1.1"
authors = [
  { name="Example Author", email="author@example.com" },
]
description = "A small example package"
readme = "README.md"
requires-python = ">=3.8"
classifiers = [
    "Programming Language :: Python :: 3",
    "License :: OSI Approved :: MIT License",
    "Operating System :: OS Independent",
]

[project.urls]
Homepage = "https://github.com/pypa/sampleproject"
Issues = "https://github.com/pypa/sampleproject/issues"


You declared build dependency on setuptools>=61.0 but limited indices only to test.pypi.org which doesn't have setuptools; see https://test.pypi.org/project/setuptools/ — error 404. You need to allow index pypi.org: pip install --index-url https://test.pypi.org/simple/ --extra-index-url https://pypi.org/simple --no-deps example_package_brickman

This was the issue. The tutorial specifies to use test pypi but doesn’t include the parameter for getting build dependencies from pypi.
Thanks for the help!
